# type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined in react-native

Tags: react-native, material-ui, components

Using package **[@material-ui/core](https://material-ui.com/)**

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import { Colors } from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen'
import { NewsCardMaterial } from "./components/NewsCardMaterial"

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <NewsCardMaterial />
      </View>
    </>
  )
}

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
})

export default App
```

NewsCardMaterial.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card"
import CardHeader from "@material-ui/core/CardHeader"
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia"
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent"
import { red } from "@material-ui/core/colors"

const UseStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 345
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: "56.25%" // 16:9
  },
  expand: {
    transform: "rotate(0deg)",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest
    })
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: "rotate(180deg)"
  },
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500]
  }
}))

const MyText = " This impressive paella is a perfect party dish and a fun meal to cook" +
  "together with your guests. Add 1 cup of frozen peas along with the" +
  "mussels, if you like."

export default function NewsCardMaterial() {
  const Classes = UseStyles()
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className={Classes.root}>
        <CardHeader
          title="Shrimp and Chorizo Paella"
          subheader="September 14, 2016 | Orissa, India"
        />
        <CardMedia
          className={Classes.media}
          image={
            "https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/river-foggy-mountains-landscape_1204-511.jpg"
          }
          title="Paella dish"
        />
        <CardContent text={MyText} />
      </Card>

    </div>
  )
}
```

index.js

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

**I see the following errors -**

**Error 1**
[image]

**Error 2**
[image]

**Error 3**
[image]

**What have I tried so far -**

1. rechecking the name of the exported components at the placing of calling
2. changing NewsCardMaterial to {NewsCardMaterial} while importing
3. installed latest versions of react, react-native and @material-ui/core
4. Included  inside  and without  as well
5. Removed unnecessary comments, white spaces and formatted the document

I have a created **sandbox** here with the same code for the card, however, not able to reproduce this error here -

1. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-wji0s?file=/demo.js
2. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-card-styling-example-forked-t7bu9?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, unfortunately Material UI is not a library for `react-native`. You didn't reproduce the error in codesandbox because codesandbox is made in `react js`. The closest library to Material UI for react-native is [react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui).

**EDIT**

For example, if you want to use react-native-material-ui `Card` component, after installed library:

```
npm install --save react-native-material-ui
```

it's just necessary to:

```
import { Card } from 'react-native-material-ui';
...
return(
    <View>
      <Card>
        // here card content
      </Card>
    </View>
)
```

and the result is:

[image]

Quite minimal but highly customizable :)

Comment: I shall try creating cards with your mentioned library, but not sure if it would be seamless. Anyways, I was earlier using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-cards  - However, this package is not most commonly used or updated! If you have any other recommendations for cards in react-native, do let me know!

Comment: Ciao @Mansi, I just added a Card example on my answer. Maybe could help. Sorry for late response :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `NewsCardMaterial.js` You are exporting as default

```
export default function NewsCardMaterial()
```

But importing it like so:

```
import { NewsCardMaterial } from "./components/NewsCardMaterial"
```

Solution is either to import like so

```
import NewsCardMaterial from "./components/NewsCardMaterial"
```

or

Export it like so:

```
export function NewsCardMaterial()
```

Comment: I tried these steps, and now with your answer, I even tried export function Component(), but I am getting more errors now!

Errors: View config getter callback for component `div` must be a function (received `undefined`) 

Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see anywhere that says Material UI supports React Native. Maybe you want to check out [react-native-paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/) that is build with Googles Material Design principles?